# Android Inflateexception / OutOfMemory

Tags: android

I'm currently working on an Android app and the whole app was running fine until I tried to add a Splashscreen before my Main activity. My main activity consists of a settings drawer on the right side, which causes the app to crash because of its background image. When removing this background image the app runs fine with the splashscreen. The crash occurs when navigating from the Splashscreen to the Main activity.

The splashscreen also consists of two images, removing the background image of the splashscreen also makes the app run fine again. Because of this I tried to reduce the sizes of the images up to a point where they are no more than 78kb and 17kb, but even with these sizes it is giving me the inflateexception/ OutOfMemory. Hope someone knows a solution to this, because I do need the images for both the splashscreen and background of the settings drawer.

Error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nl.myApp.myApp/nl.myApp.tabs.agenda.AgendaActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2814)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at nl.myApp.drawerNavigation.SettingsDrawer.onCreateView(SettingsDrawer.java:43)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at nl.myApp.tabs.agenda.AgendaActivity.onCreate(AgendaActivity.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at nl.myApp.drawerNavigation.SettingsDrawer.onCreateView(SettingsDrawer.java:43)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at nl.myApp.tabs.agenda.AgendaActivity.onCreate(AgendaActivity.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2879)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:182)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1475)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 64032012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 36MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:816)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:63
```

Splashscreen XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Splashscreen">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen_night2"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashscreen_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="64dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_night"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Settings Drawer XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="nl.myApp.drawerNavigation.SettingsDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_sidemenu_blur" >

        <!-- Content -->

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: See recycle method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle(). Call it when you don't need a loaded bitmap. Maybe this is a problem.

Comment: Please show the code of "AgendaActivity".

Comment: What is the size (in pixels) of those images ? The compressed size doesn't matter, even if your image is encoded into a 15kB file but is 1000x1000, the Bitmap built from it will be 1000x1000 and will occupy a lot of memory (around 4M bytes in ARG8888)

Comment: @Gordak Thanks! That was the problem, the splashscreen image was 2000 X 1500 and the background of the settings drawer was 1300 x 750. Reducing these values made the app runnable again. Never knew the size of the Bitmap built from that depends on the size, makes sense of course :)